# ruby on rails back-end taxi booking app

Tags: web-apps, software-development, web-development, ruby-on-rails

Can anyone direct me to a good open-source ruby on rails back-end taxi booking app with distance and price calculator for clients?

Comment: The app should be the main booking system of the taxi company? Or do you already have a booking system, and just need to interface with it?

Comment: The app will be the main booking system of the taxi company. I can develop something from scratch but i was wondering if there is already a partial solution out there that i might implement and add features to as opposed to re-inventing the wheel.